# Can't connect to RDS in Asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-rds, aws-rds-data-service

I've created a MySQL RDS on AWS console. Then I successfully connected to that RDS in MySQL Workbench using following steps:

1. Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
2. Hostname: zargham.ccir1327bjhl.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
3. Port: 3306
4. Username: [given at the time of RDS creation]
5. Password: [given at the time of RDS creation]

Then I try to connect it in my Asp.net core application, and it is giving me error on openConnection(). Following connection string is used:

**"Server=zargham.ccir1327bjhl.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com; Port=3306; Database=aws; Uid=[same as above]; Pwd=[correct Password];"**

Although OpenConnection() successful when I connect to localhost on same port.

[image: Exception Image]  [image: In-bound access AWS Image]  [image: Out-bound access AWS Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVP9App.Models
{
  public class Helptest
  {
    public static string GetRDSConnectionString()
    {
      var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

      string dbname = appConfig["RDS_DB_NAME"];

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbname)) return null;

      string username = appConfig["<<RDSUSERNAME>>"];
      string password = appConfig["<<RDSPASSWORD>>"];
      string hostname = appConfig["<<RDSHOSTNAME>>"];
      string port = appConfig["<<RDSPORT>>"];

      return "Data Source=" + hostname + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + username + ";Password=" + password + ";";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think there is no app.config file in Asp.net core application. Instead of ap.config we use appsettings.json in Asp.net core. And I already specify my connectionstring in appsettingts.json file.

Comment: check with this? https://naveenvasamsetty.wordpress.com/using-rds-with-asp-net-applications/

Comment: I followed same steps. I allowed all TCP to access my DB. Still there is error on openConnection() :'(

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=129700 - check and follow the answer

Comment: still same problem. Although when I deploy my application on elastic beanstalk, it working fine.

Comment: Although It won't help me and I already tried these link. But thanks for your time. I'll mark you.